# Something strange about position:absolute in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

then, here is the CSS:

```
.content{
    height: 155px;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
}

.board{
    -moz-box-align: stretch;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

the problem is: the .board div should be exactly the same as the .content div. However, the .board div appears to move downwards a bit, Here is the jsFiddle(open it in FireFox!): http://jsfiddle.net/hxhxhx33/5etU5/

I think the problem is at the "position:absolute: of the .content div..

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the `position:absolute;`, it's the `display: -moz-box;` causing the issue.

To compensate, give `.board` a `position:inherit;`

http://jsfiddle.net/5etU5/1/

Comment: @alienwebguy moz-box is the problem,__removing it__ or making it `block` solves the problem,doesnt it ??.. what does it have anything to do with the position??.. just curious..

Comment: Yes removing it will fix it but he probably has that CSS property there for a reason :)